# How to not get emails you send on an Microsoft Exchange distribution list?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

When we used to run our own Exchange server I do not recall getting emails sent back to me that I sent to a distribution list of which I'm a member. However, in our current situation I am getting emails that I sent. Is this standard Exchange behavior?

Is there a way to control whether you get your own emails sent back to you when sent to a distribution list that you are on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A message sent to a distribution list is delivered to all users that belongs to that DL; this is standard Exchange behaviour, and there's no way (at least that I know of) to avoid it.

You can set up a rule in Outlook to automatically move it to a different folder or plainly delete it, though.

Comment: I've never seen Exchange do anything but the described behavior, unless you also CC yourself, in which case you'll only get a single copy of the email.